# How to change the space between text in footnotes?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, titles

I have a little problem with the space between the margin of the page and the text in the footnotes when I use footnote in the title with `\maketitle` as an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \title{a title\footnote{a footnote}}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

[image: <code>space between the foot note and the margin</code>]

How can I set the space between the last line of the footnote and the bottom margin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert a vertical strut that may be as deep as you want to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\title{a title\footnote{\protect\rule[-2\baselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}a footnote}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Since you're using `\footnote` inside a `\title`, you need to `\protect` the `\rule`.